# Group By Only For One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi everybody i have the next Query

```
 SELECT 
     ges_gestor_id,
     spo_sponsor_id,
     crt_numinterno_id,
     crt_version_id, 
     car_fecemision,
     car_fecvncmto,
     car_pribruta_t,
     car_signo,
     car_numcuota_id,
     CASE Sum(car_pribruta_t * car_signo) 
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Cobrado' 
          ELSE 'Pendiente' 
     END AS car_deuda 
 FROM Cartera
 WHERE crt_numinterno_id = 287623
 GROUP BY crt_numinterno_id
```

im trying to group by this query only by one column. I remember that i see one form to do this in SQL Server 2008 using rownumber and over partition but i'm new in SQL Server and i don't know how do this. Somebody could help me please. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is the final purpose of your select in which you might need grouping on one column?

Comment: everything that is not part of the aggregate function must be part of the group.  You can make a subquery if you need to.

Comment: Well in the query i use a Sum to see if a person have any liabilities if this Sum is 0 the status is paid but if is different the status is pending but i need show in my query the date so when i put the day the query give me repeting rows but it i need only group by one column

Comment: So, you want several rows returned, and the same car_deuda in each?

Comment: I uploaded a image with the bad result if you see i have 2 rows because the group by with the column date, but if i delete the other columns i get only one row and that row is correct

Comment: The only diff I see is in car_signo column. For the columns not grouped on, would you use a max value or something else? See the proposed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be something like this?

```
 SELECT 
     max(ges_gestor_id),
     max(spo_sponsor_id),
     max(crt_numinterno_id),
     max(crt_version_id), 
     max(car_fecemision),
     max(car_fecvncmto),
     max(car_pribruta_t),
     max(car_signo),
     max(car_numcuota_id),
     CASE Sum(car_pribruta_t * car_signo) 
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Cobrado' 
          ELSE 'Pendiente' 
     END AS car_deuda 
 FROM Cartera
 WHERE crt_numinterno_id = 287623
 GROUP BY crt_numinterno_id
```

Comment: Hi that work good but i wanna know if using with, over partition and row number work this too because i see sometimes use these function to group by only for some columns

Comment: Yes, you can use `SUM(car_pribruta_t * car_signo) OVER()` variance, but IMO this is more readable. And you should group it by something anyway as I can see it.